# How to get the value by column name at runtime for a Lookup instead of column index number?

Tags: c#

I can get the value for the lookup at runtime:

```
Id = this.dgDevLkp[row, 3].ToString().TrimEnd();
```

I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

```
Id = this.dgDevLkp[row, columnName].ToString().TrimEnd();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is dgDevLkp?

Comment: Hmm dg... maybe a DataGrid? Just a guess though...

Comment: What kind of `Lookup` are you talking of? It is not a [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Asp.net? winform? MVC? WTF.Net? How do you populate your dg? What is a dg? does DG stands for **divine genius**, which allows us to guess your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestions

The following code worked for me

```
int ColumnIndex = this.dsDevLkp.Tables[dgtbsDevLkp.MappingName].Columns["ColumnName"].Ordinal;
Id = this.dgDevLkp[row, ColumnIndex].ToString().TrimEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the DataGridViewColumn's `Index` property?

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index.aspx)

E.g.:

```
Id = this.dgDevLkp[row, columnName.Index].ToString().TrimEnd();
```

Where "columnName" is the name of your DataGridViewColumn.

Comment: I think that `columName` should be a string. And the OP talks about a DataGrid not a DataGridView.